# How to start Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Good day.
I just have started to work with laravel and i can't figured out how to set my url to get to the start page or controller.
In my routes.php i put:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

Then i try the url:
http://localhost/laravel/index.php/users
http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/users

None of them works. Shows 404 error. I'm using Openserver.
In documentation there is nothing about the problem. How do i get started?

Comment: laravel page were served in `/public` directory, assuming your laravel inside laravel directory, it should be `http://localhost/laravel/public`. also to note, laravel shipped with `.htaccess` that practically hides the `index.php` so, you access your routes without it, like `http://localhost/laravel/public/users`.

Comment: Just tried it and it redirects me to http://localhost/laravel/public with 404 error. Just forgot to say, i copy all laravel framework folder from another computer. Could it create this problem?

Comment: i don't think copying a laravel framework folder from another computer could actually make a 404 problem. i wonder, if it an openserver related problem. - just to make sure, the public folder are still there right? and have an `index.php` file.

Comment: Yes, all there. Could it probably be an .htaccess configurations? What i have: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

  
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: well, then, the one who throws 404, `apache` or `nginx`? i suspect one of them is the actual culprit.

Comment: I guess you were right it is a problem with Openserver. I tried another local test domen and it is also has 404. I'll try tommorow from my work computer. Thank's for help.

Comment: the `.htaccess` is ok, it's shipped with laravel. i wonder if you could actually access laravel directory through localhost. anyway, this apache related problem - perhaps you could start with the `httpd.conf` file. and going deeper, are openserver services accessible? i'm not experienced with openserver, but there are many possibilities open, [like this](http://open-server.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1212)

Comment: If you want to get it up and running easily for development, there's always the option of running `php artisan serve` in your application directory, which will use the PHP built-in webserver. Then you can access the app at `http://localhost:8000/` and all routes should be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

Turn of your apache in zampp and go to project directory with command line
and write this code

```
php artisan serve
```

Now open laravel with localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000

and your can read the laravel document in laravel.com